# Zf2. literal route - how would I make sure that query param is present and is numeric?

Tags: zend-framework2

When routing - how would I make sure that some query params are present and are numeric?
For example - here's the route:

```
'route' => array(
    'type' => 'literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/simple_route',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'action' => 'simpleRoute'
        )
    ),
),
```

How would I make sure that `var1` and `var2` query params are present and numeric? and if not present - how would I set them to some defaults in routematch?

this should work:

```
/simple_route?var1=10&var2=15
```

and this should work:

```
/simple_route?var1=20&var2=352
```

but when not numeric - var2 should be set to some numeric default:

```
/simple_route?var1=10&var2=aabbcc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query params are not part of the routing mechanism and ignored by the router, so you cannot set any constraints on them in the router configuration.
You can check the query params for correctness within your action. i.e.

```
public function myAction()
{
    $var1 = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('var1');
    if ($var1 === null || !is_numeric($var1)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('var1 is invalid');
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

It seems there is a [Query route](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-query) indeed, but there is no possibility to add constraints on the params. So my solution for validating the params is still correct.

Comment: wait - so - why is there a 'query' route if you cannot route with it?.. but I guess that's another question - I'll ask it separately. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the 'query' route, didn't know that it exists. I have edited my answer post.

Answer (score 0):

***Query route is deprecated for [security reasons](http://framework.zend.com/security/advisory/ZF2013-01) and should not be used (it also doesn't actually match anything so it doesn't address the problem at hand).***

TLDR; This pattern is not RESTful so the ZF2 folks don't want to encourage it.  Instead, the recommended strategy is to create an Action that redirects based on query parameters. I was actually trying to replace this approach, but have reverted to it.

===

If you want/need to support it anyway, I developed a [custom Route](https://github.com/claytondaley/LegacyRS/blob/83c07c7e6d07578a9d600e7457c554ef288cd197/src/LegacyRS/Router/QueryFilter.php) with these capabilities during my search.  You could do something similar.

Unfortunately, there are gotchas.  The key one is that the Route stops looking when it runs out of path.  For example, if you send the uri `login.php?logout=true` to a Literal route for `login.php`, it will:

- match login.php
- realize there's no path left to match and
- stop searching (even if $may_terminate is set to false)

This means it never reaches the QueryFilter to have any chance to match `logout=true`. The best way I found to overcome this issue is to leave a character out.  For example, the Literal `login.ph` will leave a final `p` needing matched and continue to search and match the QueryFilter.  This is ugly, but it works.

I abandoned the QueryFilter when I decided not to use it.  If you decided to use it over the RESTful objections, I recommend some upgrades:

- Replace `exists` with `contains` using the pattern `param => bool`.  This would let you say that the query string must include (`true`) or exclude (`false`) a particular `param`.
- Add `array_key_exists` logic to the `constraints` section.

The OP's situation could be addressed by combining `contains` rules like `var1 => true` with `constraints` rules like `var1 => '[0-9]+'`.